# Vim: map shift-K to open help on current word in a new tab

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, remapping, keymap, help-files

In conjunction with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131393/remapping-help-in-vim-to-open-in-a-new-tab , I'm looking to also make the shift-K shortcut that opens help in a new tab.

I first tried `nmap <S-K> :tab help expand("<cword>")<CR>`, but it doesn't actually work - the `expand` is apparently taken literally as the help tag text, and is not executed.

So, how do I remap `<S-K>` to get help on the current word in a new tab in Vim?

Comment: I was going to recommend asking over at [Vi and Vim.SE](http://vi.stackexchange.com), but is there a reason you asked here instead?

Comment: @bertieb No specific reason except the assumption that, with a larger userbase, there might be more probability of getting an answer here. It has turned out my question contained two parts, so I'll now take the unanswered part over to [vi.se] and try it out there.

Comment: I saw you were aware of them so figured it would be something along those lines, cheers :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do. `<s-k>`, also known as `K`, opens the man page for the keyword under the cursor. I assume you want to create a mapping to open the vim help page for the keyword under the cursor. This can be done by this (i'll use `<c-k>` to not override `K`):

```
noremap <c-k> :execute "tab h " . expand("<cword>")<cr>
```

Comment: "<s-k>, also known as K, opens the man page" <- This is actually incorrect: it opens whatever the current `keywordprg` program is, depending on the filetype; its default is `man`, but the `keywordprg` automatically changes to `:help` when in a vimscript file, and can be set to for eg. `perldoc -f` for filetype perl, to automatically get perldoc help within Perl files when `K` is pressed.

Comment: What I wanted was a way to take this whole thing and just add the feature of opening the output in a new tab. Your `execute` idea did help me make this work just for vim keywords at least, so I'll accept your answer and split the question about making this portable for any value of `keywordprg` a separate question (since that looks to be a more complicated requirement).

Comment: I see what you are trying to do. You can achieve this with this mapping (i'll use <c-k> again): `nnoremap <c-k> :execute 'tabnew <bar> read !' . &keywordprg . ' ' . expand("<cword>")<cr>`

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of anyone stumbling upon this later: I combined the two methods mentioned in @madmax1's answer and comment, to make Vim choose the appropriate method of help automatically depending on the filetype.

```
function! GetHelpOnCwordInTab()
    if &filetype == "vim"
        execute 'tab help ' . expand("<cword>")
    else
        execute 'tabnew <bar> read ! ' . &keywordprg . expand("<cword>")
    endif 
endfunction
autocmd FileType * nnoremap <C-K> :call GetHelpOnCwordInTab()<CR>
```

(I had to take @madmax1's suggestion on keymapping too (`C-K` instead of `S-K`) because [Scriptease](https://github.com/tpope/vim-scriptease) has an autocmd overwriting the `S-K` mapping, and I'm not sure how to override that from within .vimrc.)